# Not able to send Event Hit in google analytics using measurement protocol

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I recently created a new Google analytics account for testing purpose and for this account(tracking id) sending event hit, pageview hit and exception hit using measurement protocol(server-side protocol) is working and I am able to view statistics in google analytics.

But when I try to use tracking id from an old google analytics account (which is used in my production environment and it has been used to send event hit and pageview hit using analytics.js), google analytics doesn't show event hits or pageview hits sent using measurement protocol(server-side protocol).

Any help will be appreciated. Do we have to enable accepting requests from measurement protocol somewhere in google analytics or developer console settings?

Comment: You might try verifying the hits with the [hit builder tool](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/), and monitoring the real-time dashboard as you send hits from the tool. You should also verify that there are no differing filters applied to the view.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue while testing on the hit builder tool, and the issue was that I was filtering my IP from Analytics so the events weren't showing on the real time dashboard. I removed the filter and the events started showing up.